# De tibble a vector

Tags: r

Despues de leer un excel con `read_excel` obtengo un tibble de una sola fila, sin nombre de cabecera.

Dato

```
A tibble: 1 × 3
   ...1  ...2  ...3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10     2     5
```

Quiero pasarlo a vector, pero no lo consigo. He probado como `as.vector`, con `pull` y `deframe` pero no doy con la tecla.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo tengo

```
as.vector(simplify2array(Dato))
```

Aunque seguro que hay mejores formas